# Vectorize prod with rolling mask in NumPy

Tags: numpy, vectorization, product

I am trying to vectorize the product of n-1 entries of a vector x in NumPy with what I think would be a kind of rolling mask. Basically, what I would like to get is a vector v such that

```
    for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]):
      v[i] = np.prod(x[:i]) * np.prod(x[i+1:])
```

Is there a way to avoid the loop? The only solution I came up with is to build a NxN tensor, set the diagonal to the identity and then call prod on one axis. That's OK if x is a vector and I only have to skip a single index, but in other cases x can be M x N and I need to skip more (say |I| many) which requires creating a M x N^(|I|+1) tensor, which ends up taking A LOT of time.

Comment: Is `v[i]=prod(x)/x[i]` an option? (Does not work, if there may be zeros in `x`)

Comment: Unfortunately there can be zeros in x

Comment: If there is more than one `0`, all partial products should be zero, if there is exactly one `0`, you'd need to only calculate the corresponding product (but having to count the number of zeros first may make this inefficient ...)